# Arduino VS Stand-alone Microcontroller for a Beginner

Tags: arduino

Wes geo hal,

I am relatively new to microcontrollers, and I intend to start with them in my electronics hobby and school projects. Although, I am rather confused whether I shall initiated with Arduino, PICAXE, or straight into static microcontrollers, that is PICs, AVRs?

Before you identify that Arduino is a microcontroller, I mean what environment shall I practise, that is the fully supported development boards and programming of Arduino, or the direct programming of static microcontrollers? I enquire this, because I have found people stating on other forums of discussion that Arduino does not help beginners get into understanding microcontrollers fully while researching this enquiry.

Essentialy, my question is am I better to start with Arduino environemnt, or PICAXE, or a stand-alone microcontroller development?

Comment: Unfortunately the answers to this question are going to be opinion based, and the correct answer will be dependent on your capabilities.  In my opinion as an absolute beginner you are probably better off with the ready made boards and easy programing of an Arduino type product, you can extend the complexity of what you are doing as you get more understanding of the device but still do some interesting stuff initially from a high level.

Comment: *Arduino does not help beginners get into understanding microcontrollers fully* And I expect people who write such statements to also not "fully" understand a microcontroller. I mean, there is always a level where understanding stops. You **can** use a uC perfectly without understanding how an NMOS transistor works. Is an Arduino good enough to learn and use a uC ? I believe it is. What is "fully understanding" anyway ? Learn to program in assembler ? That is only helpful in some situations. 99% of Arduino hobbyists don't need to know this. And when they do, they can always learn at that time.

Comment: I agree with @FakeMoustache - there is nothing wrong with a simplified beginner-friendly system, and there's a definite "elitist" tendency to oppose things that simplify complex systems. So long as people are aware that Arduino is not the whole story, this is not a problem.

Comment: Either way will work, so it really depends on if you are more interested in the hardware and low level details or primarily just want to write software that has an interface to the outside world. If it's the latter, you might also want to consider a single board computer such as the raspberry pi.

Comment: @FakeMoustache I agree. And btw. also in the arduino environment you can go down to direct port and register manipulation. Arduino just provides a higher level language that is easier to understand for beginners.

Comment: Perhaps it is best to provide an example of these discussions: [link](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/witch-microcontroller-should-i-learn/)[/link]. My main concern is can I place, that is solder, the Arduino microcontroller, not the development board, the individual AVR for a project?

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently in my second year of studies at a public university in the US.
I started out on the Arduino on my own in high school, although my later classes (my intro embedded class) used a TI MSP430.

The Arduino has the benefit of being well supported by hobbyists with good tutorials for beginners, but as it seems, won't really earn you the respect of a "true embedded systems" developer, as far as I can tell, more or less what you gather.

If you're looking for a gentle introduction to embedded systems, I would say the Arduino is the way to go. Otherwise, as you have mentioned, there's plenty of other places to go, and frankly the Arduino often is not the best choice when considering hobbyist projects. In that case, I'd think a chip like the MSP430 (the value line development board) is a cheap and effective way to learn about microcontrollers, likely giving you more options, at the cost of a steeper learning curve.

In any case, as there are many microcontroller development boards today, perhaps it is more important that you gain experience with one system, and then broaden your knowledge to be able to handle things more generally. Jumping in and getting your feet wet is probably more important than finding a specific chip, since you aren't exactly trying to design a product with a specific application in mind - you are simply learning about microcontrollers.

Answer (score 2):

An Arduino typically consists of an AVR chip and lots of software.

It is the software libraries that abstract away much of the microcontroller hardware peculiarities, and which differentiate the Arduinos from most other development boards. However, you are not forced to always use these libraries; your programs can instead access the hardware directly.

So you could begin with the Arduino libraries (which *are* easier), and later switch over to treating the Arduino just like a plain AVR board.

Please note that there are Arduino-compatible libraries for many other microcontroller boards (e.g., [Energia](http://energia.nu/) for TI LaunchPads, or [Arduino for STM32](http://www.stm32duino.com/)). Choose whichever one you can find the best support for in your environment.

Answer (score -1):

Just as you mentioned, Arduino is a microcontroller designed for beginner and hobbyist. There is lots of tutorial to get start with, active community and many driver for sensors (or other kind of device) available in open source. Since it's design for hobbyist, there is no need to understand the architecture, register or assembly to make your code work.

If you want to learn more from microcontroller, you rather use Microchip's PIC ou TI's MSP430. It's harder to use since you need to understand how does the µC work but this knowledge will be useful for your school.

I advice you to learn how does Microchip's PIC works since it's more common in industry (in my experience)

I hope this will help you ;)

Comment: To be more precise: **Arduino** is indeed designed for Hobbyists, but **Arduino** uses an Atmega microcontroller (which, by itself, is **NOT** designed for hobbyists) on a PCB with all the support components and connectors it needs to make an **easy to use platform**. To this, software, libraries and documentation are added to make the platform easy to use and suitable for hobbyists.

Answer (score -1):

It is in the chip vendors best interest to provide libraries for their products, libraries that hide the details (and much of the experience).  Making it the same as writing a program on windows or linux or mac, you are just making api calls.  If that is the experience you are after, then one is as good as another, arduino is very popular sure, but there is also mbed.

The AVR is not the first microcontroller I would choose if you are wanting to dive in deeper I would recommend the msp430 or something cortex-m based, TI's documentation is some of the best (Microchip on the lower end), ST and NXP being pretty good.  Ti has launchpad boards for msp430, cortex-ms and their dsps, in the ball park or much less than an arduino but very capable in some cases way more capable than an arduino.  ST offers the nucleo series boards which sit between the arduino experience and mbed, perhaps supported in both worlds.  Super easy to program you just drag and drop your binary into a virtual usb drive provided by the debugger end of the board, and very price competitive, can get a good one for $10.

The other vendors have somewhat missed the boat on really easy to use eval/hobby boards, but you can still find something.

If you are only interested in api calls and dont want to know what is going on, get an arduino and and mbed and use those environments.  Even if you want to dig deeper you should still experience a few high level environments including what the chip vendors offer, you may/will need to be able to use those in that form professionally.  Likewise since those libraries have issues in various forms it is good to also get your hands dirty and understand how the chips boot and how to configure them at the register level as well as some instruction set basics, they all have something to offer, msp430, cortex-m, avr, pic, the more the better, there are instruction set simulators that you can try for free to get a feel for the chip since there is a high failure rate (you cant see what is going on when your program hangs, harder to debug, can and will brick chips, it happens even with decades experience, but they are cheap).

With say an msp430 launchpad and one of the nucleo boards with jumpers on the SWD interface you can then go build your own boards or buy really inexpensive ones on ebay from asia, not that you have to have these debug headers a $2 ftdi usb to uart will get you into the bootloaders on a number of these vendors products.  You can also get parts sampled from the chip vendors (that means a few parts for free) and some inexpensive tssop or other breakout boards, again hooking up to say a nucleo top end or launchpad or other dev board.

Try one like a ti msp430 or stm32 cortex-m and get your feet wet, then dive into some others.  Even if you have a bad experience, come back a couple three years later and see if it has changed, professionally until you are the lead engineer you may get stuck on a project with one the products on your not favorite list and have to just deal with it, be flexible and able to adapt.

Answer (score -1):

Starting with Arduino is probably the best.  It'll get you the basic idea of running stuff on real hardware.

As a colleague found out recently though, Arduino is not friendly for experts.  You can't just unslot the Arduino "easy" version and change to a hardcore AVR "expert mode" - when it comes to I/O, you need to completely ditch the Arduino code and start from scratch with AVR.  I'd still recommend sticking with Arduino though, because by the time you get to needing that kind of expert-mode hacking for ultimate performance, you'll have your circuit boards finished off.  That means you're only changing one thing at once, instead of having to work out how to set up the circuit board *and* some very complicated software at the same time, and not being sure which is the one causing your faults.

Driving the I/O on a complex microcontroller at register level is not a mission for a newbie.  Simple digital I/O is not too hard (although even then you have the happy joy of pinmux, pin directions and pull-up/down to consider), but when you get onto programming timers, ADCs, DACs and comms peripherals, it pretty much takes line-by-line memorisation of that part of the spec to get it right, sometimes with trips to Stack Overflow or the manufacturer's forums for the things they forgot to document.  I've been doing this for 25 years so I get it right more often than not, but "not" is still a very frequently-encountered option!  I wouldn't want to be hacking on this unless I had some solid experience with general embedded programming leading up to it.  So definitely start on the easy option and work upwards, because starting on the harder option is a learning curve of pure ice-covered glass.

If you're planning on replacing the I/O functions at some point, this also should lead you in the direction of writing well-constructed code with an I/O abstraction layer.  That lets you write the main application code, and have the main application call functions named something like `set_power_led_red()`.  You can implement  `set_power_led_red()` for Arduino to call the right things, and then when you change to AVR you can blow away that C file and implement `set_power_led_red()` for the new AVR setup instead.  That lets you slot out the Arduino I/O code, write some AVR code, and hopefully not have to make too many changes to the rest of the application.  And for bonus points you could also put in a stub for `set_power_led_red()` and run tests on the application code under Visual C on Windows, instead of having to do all your debugging on the actual hardware which can be inconvenient at times.  Hardware abstraction is definitely your friend.